# Query product list with quantity bought for each

Tags: mysql

My MySQL isn't as sharp as others and I've been trying to figure this out for the past hour. Maybe you can point me in the right direction. I have a list of products and I'm trying to get a report out of them. This is what I have:

```
-- Product list: tbl_products
id       product_name
------  ----------------
1        Hamburger
2        Cheeseburger
3        Burger Balls


-- List of orders: tbl_orders
id       created
------  -----------------------
23       2013-09-04 00:00:00
45       2013-09-05 00:00:00
67       2013-09-09 00:00:00


-- Products bought per order: tbl_product_orders
order_id    product_id      quantity
----------  --------------  --------
23          1                4
23          2                6
45          1                1
67          3                2
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve with one query:

```
-- How do I get this
order_id    Hamburger     Cheeseburger    Burger Balls
----------  ------------- --------------- --------------
23           4             6               0
45           1             0               0
67           0             0               2
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

**Edit:**
I'll post my earlier scripts in a bit. I just have to run to class right now. :)

Comment: Yes You can do this..??? can you share your efforts..?

Comment: Trying to make dynamic columns in SQL usually doesn't end well. Select the data you need and create the final result in the application.

Comment: don't go for dynamic column names, it's not what sql is made for. If you need something like that, look at XMLA or sql attrib models

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with dynamic SQL

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN product_id = ', id,
                           ' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) `', product_name, '`'))
  INTO @sql
  FROM tbl_products;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT order_id,', @sql,
                  '  FROM tbl_product_orders
                    GROUP BY order_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
| ORDER_ID | HAMBURGER | CHEESEBURGER | BURGER BALLS |
|----------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|       23 |         4 |            6 |            0 |
|       45 |         1 |            0 |            0 |
|       67 |         0 |            0 |            2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/272d2/3)** demo

---

To simplify things on calling end you can wrap it into a stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_report()
BEGIN
  SET @sql = NULL;

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN product_id = ', id,
                             ' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) `', product_name, '`'))
    INTO @sql
    FROM tbl_products;

  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT order_id,', @sql,
                    '  FROM tbl_product_orders
                      GROUP BY order_id');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98300/1)** demo

Comment: Works great. I've never used stored procedures before so this was a real eye-opener. Is `DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;` really required?

Comment: @enchance It will work without `DEALLOCATE` but you better use it if you no longer need a prepared statement. Otherwise `stmt` will live until the session is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

this will work, only one join:

```
select order_id,
sum(if(product_orders.product_id=1, product_orders.quantity, 0)) as hamburglars,
sum(if(product_orders.product_id=2, product_orders.quantity, 0)) as cheese_burglars,
sum(if(product_orders.product_id=3, product_orders.quantity, 0)) as burglar_balls
from orders inner join product_orders on orders.id=product_orders.order_id
group by order_id
```

Comment: go with the dynamic sql then, or use xmla.
check EAV model on wiki

Comment: What's wrong with this answer? It works fine. Am I missing something here?

Comment: nope. works fine, but if you add a row in the products table, a new column is not automatically created in the query output. it was not mentioned as a requirement but jaczes misunderstood.

Comment: I love this answer as well since it's very straight forward. If I could choose 2 answers this would definitely be the other one.

Comment: THanks! coming from BI where you have huge routines to maintain, I like to keep column names the same regardless of how data changes. Easier to fix missing data in a column while the rest is fine, than to find in the morning that your routine stopped due to an error and no data has been calculated ;)